# send email when created spot instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i want that in my email send notification, when for example in dev created spot instance  or created spot instance request, but email not send. what is wrong in this code?

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "spot_instance_notification" {
  name = "SpotInstanceNotificationTopic"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "spot_instance_creation_rule" {
  name = "SpotInstanceCreationRule"

  event_pattern = <<EOF
  {
    "source": ["aws.ec2"],
    "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
    "detail": {
      "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com",
      "rds.amazonaws.com",
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
      "eventName": ["RequestSpotInstances"]
    }
  }
  EOF
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "sns_target" {
  rule        = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.spot_instance_creation_rule.name
  target_id   = "spot-instance-sns-target"
  arn         = aws_sns_topic.spot_instance_notification.arn
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "email_subscription" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.spot_instance_notification.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "myemail@gmail.com" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#argument-reference), there is a note:

> In order to be able to have your AWS Lambda function or SNS topic invoked by an EventBridge rule, you must set up the right permissions using `aws_lambda_permission` or `aws_sns_topic_policy`.

So that means you need to add the SNS topic policy, which would allow the EventBridge rule to invoke the SNS topic. The documentation for the topic policy is [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_policy). You can take a look in the AWS documentation for the SNS topic policy [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-use-resource-based.html#eb-sns-permissions).

Comment: and answer me please  "eventName": ["RequestSpotInstances"] is normal or we have other right eventName?

Comment: That is a different question compared to the first one, so I would suggest creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.spot_instance_notification.arn

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid = "AllowEventBridgeToPublish",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "events.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = "SNS:Publish",
        Resource = aws_sns_topic.spot_instance_notification.arn,
      }
    ]
  })
}
```